# How to replace old value in C++ loop?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, angle

I am trying to write a program that will run through angles a catapult could shoot from, from 0-90, and calculate the the distance each will result in. When an angle results in a farther distance than the last, it should replace the previous angle in a variable called "bestAngle". This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double g = 9.8;
    double v,a,d,bestAngle;

    for(a=0; a<=90; ++a){
        double rad = a*3.14159/180;
        if(a<=30){
            v=45;
        }else if(a>30 && a<=60){
            v = 40;
        }else{
            v=30;   
        }

        d = pow(v,2)*sin(2*rad)/g;
        double bestAngle = 0;
        double bestAngleRad = bestAngle*3.14159/180;
        if(d>pow(v,2)*sin(a*bestAngleRad)/g){
            bestAngle = a;
            bestAngleRad = bestAngle*3.14159/180;
        }
    }

    cout << bestAngle << endl;
}
```

I think the problem has something to do with the last if statement, as I think the best angle is not updating. I don't expect anyone to tell me exactly what to do, but if someone could point me to the location of the error that would be helpful.

Comment: Don't post code picture here.

Comment: You have two variables called `bestAngle`. That's going to confuse you.

Comment: Please give us some normal well formatted code in the text format

Answer (score 1):

bestAngle is not updating, because your outer bestAngle is replaced by redefined bestAngle with scope inside your for cycle. Once you exit the cycle, inner bestAngle is out of scope, and you revert back to your outer bestAngle, which has not changed. Rename your inner variable and maybe use dichotomy, since looking for function maximum the way you do it is quite ineffective.

Comment: Search term: "variable shadowing"

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems

First is that the variable bestAngle is defined twice, which is legal but not good, in you case the second shadows the first and then the setting of the `bestAngle` refers to the 2nd `bestAngle` which goes out of scope at every iteration of the loop. When it goes out of scope it is destroyed and the new `bestAngle` is lost.

The second problem is that `bestAngleRad` is defined in the loop and then goes out of scope and is lost if you had any further use of it.

And a third minor detail, you recalculate the value of `bestAngleRad`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double bestAngle = 0.0; // (1a first)

    for(a=0; a<=90; ++a){
        double bestAngle = 0; // (1b second)
        double bestAngleRad = bestAngle*3.14159/180; // (2a)
        if(d>pow(v,2)*sin(a*bestAngleRad)/g){
            bestAngle = a;
            bestAngleRad = bestAngle*3.14159/180; // (3)
        }
        // (1c, 2b second out of scope)
    }

    cout << bestAngle << endl;
}
```

What I think you intended (note code is untested)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double g = 9.8;
    double v,a,d; // bad variable names
    double bestAngle = 0,bestAngleRad = 0.0; // good variable names

    for(a=0; a<=90; ++a){
        double rad = a*3.14159/180; // rad calculated only once
        if(a<=30){
            v=45;
        }else if(a>30 && a<=60){
            v = 40;
        }else{
            v=30;   
        }

        d = pow(v,2)*sin(2*rad)/g;
        if(d>pow(v,2)*sin(a*rad)/g){
            bestAngle = a;
            bestAngleRad = rad;
        }
    }

    cout << bestAngle << endl;
}
```